# Gradle custom library in an android app

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have the following [project](https://github.com/CarefreeCoding/Gaming).

The project itself is me trying to experiment with me writing a library.

And this is what I would like to do

```
\project
|
--\android (android framework library)
|
--\androidExamples (this is where I fail)
| |
| --\game one (I would like this to be an android app)
| |
| --\game two (I would like this to be an android app)
| |
| --\game three (I would like this to be an android app)
|
--\androidUtils (android utilities library)
|
--\engine (physics engine library)
|
--\swing (swing framework library)
|
--\swingExamples
|
--\swingUtils (swing utilities library)
```

The problem I have run into is in androidExample subproject.
I would like it to have multiple subprojects where each subproject is an android app. However I do not seem to be able to posses the skills nor the knowledge to make it happen. Any pointer to an example or explanation will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "android app"? I don't think it can really be an android app which generated an apk after the compilation... your project would generate 4 apks...weird no? But you can have 3 "android-library" with activities, resources... like an application project but it will generate an .aar which is very easy to integrate in an Android application project. I am not sure I am answering your question. Can you explain why you want game_one, game_two and game_three to be android applications ?

Comment: I just want to learn gradle. I want to learn how to make jar libraries, android libraries and Android apps. I also would like to learn how to do all in one project. Are you saying that my android utils and Android framework library will not generate library?

Comment: Oh yes they willt too I was just focusing on the "android thing". The other will be jars, right ?

Comment: @ElodieFerrais yes the other things are going to be jars. But I want the androidExamples subproject to contain apps. It seems doable if androidExamples was the root project, but I can't get it to work if androidExamples is a subproject.

Comment: Let me upload an exemple and tell me if it helps.

Comment: @ElodieFerrais Thank you very much. It seems to make a lot of sense. I will try it out once I get home and if it works mark you answer as correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71514/discussion-between-elodie-ferrais-and-quillion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve it, I thing you should read this doc:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide
Specially the "Multi project setup" section.

But basically you define in your build.gradle what you want your projects to be.

An app:
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

or an android library

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

or a java project

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

All your projects has its own build.gradle

Your main project will have a file called settings.gradle where you include all the "library/sub-project" you need + itself

```
include ':app','lib1','lib2'
```

Then you will have to include all the dependencies in your main build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':lib1')
    compile project(':lib2')
}
```

So I think your project will be more something like

```
\project
|
--\android (android framework library)
|
--\androidExamples (MAIN PROJECT)
|
--\game one (android-library)
|
--\game two (android-library)
|
--\game three (android-library)
|
--\androidUtils (java)
|
--\engine (java)
|
--\swing (java)
|
--\swingExamples (do you really need it ?)
|
--\swingUtils (java)
```

Edit-

Here an example https://github.com/elodieferrais/MultiProjectSample

Comment: I looked at it and it's similar to what I have. However it doesn't solve my problem. I would like to have multiple sibprojects in androidExamples. I don't want androidExamples to just be one app, I want it to contain multiple small apps

Comment: I am 100% sure that you cannot have an app inside an app, otherwise you will have many apks, many launcher activities, many applications launch at the same time... but you can have android-libraries inside your app. Look at the branch nested-project : https://github.com/elodieferrais/MultiProjectSample/tree/nested-project